# jQuery.get not receiving data

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, rest

I have the following html + jquery:

```
<body>
    <head>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
            <script>
                $(window).load(function() {
                    $('#test').bind('click', function() {
                        $.get("http://localhost:3000/promotions.xml", function(data){
                            alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
                        });                        
                    });                 
                });
            </script>
    </head>

    <input id="test" type="button" value="Testando">
</body>
```

The problem is that the data parameter is empty, even though when I test the url on the browser I see a xml file with some data into it. I tried switching to HTML and json and it didn't work either. The server reports that everything is fine:

```
Started GET "/promotions.xml" for 127.0.0.1 at Thu Feb 10 16:02:33 -0200 2011
  Processing by PromotionsController#index as XML
  ←[1m←[35mPromotion Load (1.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "promotions".* FROM "promotions"
Completed 200 OK in 41ms (Views: 31.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

So I guess it is something in javascript/jQuery that I'm missing. I'm using jquery 1.4.4. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess that it is a result of the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript), which requires that AJAX requests be made to the same location as the page's origin.

If the page isn't hosted from `localhost:3000`, that would violate the policy.

If you're testing with Chrome, you should be able to disable the security policy by launching it from a terminal application with:

```
--disable-web-security
```